# Adding/removing rows of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have a panel and my idea is to have it populated by a stack panel containing two text boxes. When the user enters something in the left box, something should be generated in the right one, as follows.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBox Name="Lefty" LostFocus="FillMyBuddy" />
  <TextBox Name="Righty" LostFocus="FillMyBuddy" />
</StackPanel>
```

However, I'd like to add an option to add/remove rows and, since I wish not to limit myself to the number of such, I get a bit uncertain regarding the approach on two points.

1. Manipulating DOM (well, it's XAML/WPF but you see what I'm aiming at).
2. Event handling.

Is it a big no-no to programmatically affect the mark-up structure of the window? Or is it OK to add/remove panels during run-time?

What would the recommended way to be if I want the *Lefty* number 3 change stuff in *Righty* number 3? Anything more neat than checking the sender and pulling its siblings from the parent? I want to use a single event handler for any and all rows (knowing that the operations are always intra-row-wise).

Comment: What's `Remobing` is that a special technique ? lol

Comment: Neither manipulating DOM, nor event handling are applicable here. What you need is an ItemsControl and proper DataBinding.

Comment: For your case, I think a Datagrid "binded" with a collection on a ViewModel is the best approach

Comment: _bows to master @HighCore_

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, it is. When you send a mob onto a subject, it's going to get its behind kicked. When you send them again (re-mob), the subject will, wise from previous experience, run away before the behind-kicking can even commence. Hence, *remobing* is an act equivalent to **removing** something. How was it not obvious? I thought you spoke English well... (Also, I see someone already corrected the typo so we might want to **remob** our comments, teehee.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten don't be an `Idget`\

Comment: @MethodMan Hmm... I sense a pun here but I can't see it. Is it just a misspelled *idiot* or is it a method call (like get-id -> IdGet, or something)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to follow MVVM, and have no code in your code-behind (programmatically affect the mark-up structure) files.  The concept is easy when you grasp it, so learn it before you start writing your code.

In short, you are going to want to have a view model (something that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC)) which holds your collection of items (which are going to be models, or view models in pure-MVVM).  In "hybrid"-MVVM you could just have your models implement INPC.

Then, through the use of commands, you'd implement the logic to remove items from the list that its in.  You can pass references, raise notification, using event bubbling, etc. (it's your preference) to have the item actually removed.  In my case, I just passed a "manager" to the hybrid-model and held a reference to that.  When the command is called (button is clicked), the model calls for the reference to remove itself from the list.

After you do that you define a `DataTemplate` to define what an "item" should look like one the View.  You use a `ItemsControl` to show a collection of items, and bind to its `ItemsSource` so the collection of items are shown.  Set your `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to the `DataTemplate` you created, and anything added to the collection bound to `ItemsSource` of the type defined in `DataTemplate.DataType` will render as you specify in the `DataTemplate`.

At the end of the day, you should learn about MVVM design, `DataContext`, INPC, Commands, Control types and their "main" properties, e.g. everything that inherits from `ItemsControl` has an `ItemsSource` property.

Here is a working example, where changing the original string, will reverse it and put it in the read-only right side text box:

[image: Text changed, items removed, etc.]

### MainWindow.xaml.cs (code-behind)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    StructureVm _struct = new StructureVm("Test");

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = _struct;
    }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml (View)

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateWithCommands.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateWithCommands"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Orange">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}"
                      x:Key="VmItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Original, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Encoded}"
                         IsReadOnly="True" />
                <Button Content="X"
                        Command="{Binding RemoveMeCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VmItem}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Interface (helpful for Dependency Injection)

```
public interface IStructureManager
{
    bool RemoveItem(Model itemToRemove);
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public class StructureVm : IStructureManager
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Model> _items;
    private readonly string _title;

    public StructureVm(string title)
    {
        _title = title;
        _items = new ObservableCollection<Model>
            {
                new Model(this, "12"),
                new Model(this, "23"),
                new Model(this, "34"),
                new Model(this, "45"),
                new Model(this, "56"),
                new Model(this, "67"),
                new Model(this, "78"),
                new Model(this, "89"),
            };
    }}

    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
    }

    public bool RemoveItem(Model itemToRemove)
    {
        return _items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
}
```

### Model (not pure-MVVM, pure MVVM models don't implement INPC, and don't have Command in them)

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly RelayCommand _removeMe;
    private string _original;
    private string _encoded;
    private readonly IStructureManager _manager;
    public string Original
    {
        get
        {
            return _original;
        }
        set
        {
            _original = value;
            Encoded = ReverseString(_original);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Encoded
    {
        get
        {
            return _encoded;
        }
        set
        {
            _encoded = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand RemoveMeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeMe;
        }
    }

    public Model(IStructureManager manager, string original)
    {
        Original = original;
        _manager = manager;
        _removeMe = new RelayCommand(param => RemoveMe(), param => CanRemoveMe);
    }

    private void RemoveMe()
    {
        _manager.RemoveItem(this);
    }

    private bool CanRemoveMe
    {
        get
        {
            //Logic to enable/disable button
            return true;
        }
    }

    private string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### [RelayCommand implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030)

From here on out all you have to do is change the attributes of your controls to whatever you're happy with and call it good.  The example might be ugly, but I'm leaving it as an exercise for you to figure out other properties/attributes of WPF controls.

Comment: This was one kick-rectum reply. Really impressive with the code so it's definitely +1 for the effort. I've never used the *ItemsControl*, so it's cool to learn something new. Also, any idea on how the question might be improved? I seem to get negative score and I can't see why...

Comment: @KonradViltersten In short, many of the WPF questions on SO come down to 1. Your DataContext is wrong, 2. You're not notifying the view of any changes (INPC), 3. OP is so far and deep from MVVM, that they've past the point of no return.  Remember those.  Your question doesn't really show any effort and that's probably why it's getting downvoted.  Your question boils down to a introductory level, "how do I WPF?" and there is already a lot of content on SO and the web to teach you.  The reason I answered it is because I want to prevent bad practices and bad questions in the future.

Comment: A good version of your question might show XAML and your attempt to code a solution that removes items from a row in a datagrid in code-behind or something. Maybe your attempt at following MVVM and questioning why the rows aren't being updated.  The answer will still come down to one of the 3 topics listed above, but at least it shows you tried it before asking how to do it.  Essentially the question could be closed because "we are not here to do it for you."  But I saw it as an opportunity to educate.  Feel free to ask questions in [WPF Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In fact, I haven't coded that solution yet, so there's nothing to show as example. I asked before putting a lot of effort to see if there was a better way that I haven't though of. And there was! Just as you've shown. Thankful for that!